# How to show private flickr group on a Wordpress site?

Tags: gallery, private, flickr

I have been trying to embed a flickr group within a Wordpress site for our camera club using a plugin such as slicker flickr or awesome flickr gallery. I have no problems with showing a set of thumbnails of my own photo stream, galleries, sets, or of a group I am a member of. However, I cannot seem to display the originally private flickr group, changed to a public flickr group, that I am an admin for.

Any help appreciated.